# use localstorage with ng-Change doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I wrote below code

```
  var checkLightOn = $localstorage.getObject('LightOn');

  if(checkLightOn == true){
    $scope.LightOn = true;
  }else{
    $scope.LightOn = false;
  }

  $scope.checked = function(){
    if($scope.LightOn){
      $localstorage.set('LightOn','');
    }else{
      $localstorage.set('LightOn',true);
    }
  }
```

and expect my toggle with work fine with localstorage. But the second click doesn't change the localstorage's value, It work only I do the refresh. I have no idea why. I put an `alert()` within the ng-change, it trigger every time I clicked on it.

The view

```
<input ng-model="LightOn " ng-change="checked()" type="checkbox">
```

Comment: Show the part of the View that invokes `$scope.checked()`

Comment: You need to also change `$scope.LightOn` in `$scope.checked`. You can use: `$scope.LightOn = !$scope.LightOn;`

Comment: @jcubic perhaps u post it as an answer pls?

Comment: @jcubic why you deleted your answer? it was working..

Comment: Not sure why @jcubic works and yours doesn't. There is something else going on in the code you haven't posted. It works fine for me with "fake" local storage: http://plnkr.co/edit/r490FfMxgikeTsIZR13s?p=preview

Comment: @NewDev, jcubic's solution is working.

Comment: @EltonJamie, that's great... but if I were you, I would try to understand why yours wasn't. Do you have a typo with `ng-model` on your checkbox?

Comment: Not sure how `$localstorage` is working, but the browser will only store strings. So the first clause: `checkLightOn == true` will always be false (`'true' != true`) unless the `getObject()` is doing the proper conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to change the LightOn scope variable not only localStorage, try:

```
  $scope.checked = function(){
    if($scope.LightOn){
      $localstorage.set('LightOn','');
    }else{
      $localstorage.set('LightOn',true);
    }
    $scope.LightOn = !$scope.LightOn;
  }
```

Comment: Why? `LightOn` is changed via `ng-model`. This will, I'm fairly certain, revert `LightOn` to whatever it was set before

Answer (score 0):

may be something goes wrong with $localstorage I guess. I have an example here (bases on you code) and it works well. 
No need to reassign $scope.LightOn

```
Check this Link:
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0qwtbppf/1/